# How to parse a newline delimited JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I’m working with App Scripts to pull a `JSON` file from a GCS bucket. The data is stored as a newline delimited `JSON`. It arrives as a large object, which makes programmatic access to the internal data impossible.

My aim is to separate each element by `merchant_id`. I’ve attempted to split the data using `\n` as the parameter. But I’m having difficulty with converting the object to a string and back again.
Calling `JSON.parse` on the response gives me the error `Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1766`. While this does separate each of the elements within the `JSON`, calling `JSON.parse` on each individually gives me an `Unexpected end of JSON input` error.

Function

```
function myFunction() {

let url = 'url_address';
let storedData = [];
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
let str = response.toString();
let storedResponse = str.split("\n");

storedResponse.forEach((data) => {
   storedData.push(JSON.parse(data));
});
}
```

Example of `data` in the forEach

```
{"product_data_timestamp":"2021-05-06 UTC","product_id":"product_id_here","merchant_id":"merchant_id_here","aggregator_id":"agg_id_here","offer_id":"offer_id_here","title":"furniture","description":"description","link":"link","additional_image_links":[],"content_language":"en","target_country":"GB","channel":"online","google_expiration_date":"2021-05-31 22:00:27.517 UTC","availability":"in stock","brand":"brand","color":"black","condition":"new","custom_labels":{"label_0":"GBP"},"item_group_id":"id","mpn":"mpn_id","price":{"value":"129.99","currency":"GBP"},"google_product_category_ids":[],"product_type":"headboards","additional_product_types":[],"destinations":[{"name":"Shopping","status":"approved"}],"issues":[]}
```

Comment: please check your quotes - they are not the same `let url = 'url_address’;`

Comment: have you tried joining it back together?  Why do you need to convert the response explicitly to string? Also it would be really useful to add a raw dump of the server response.

Comment: I haven't tried joining it back together, do you mean replacing `\n` with `,`? I am converting to string to make use of the `split` method. Just looked into adding the server response and it's unfortunately not available

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by newline delimited JSON. Newlines in JSON are for readability unless they are part of the value of one of the keys, i.e. `{key: "value \n"}`. If it is a valid JSON structure (can you confirm its valid JSON?) then splitting by newlines will most likely produce mostly invalid JSON. So it will probably require a few more steps. You could potentially use Regex to get matches, but without seeing the original JSON its not really possible to know where you went wrong.

Comment: Also, `which makes programmatic access to the internal data impossible`  - why is this exactly? If you just run a `let json = JSON.parse(response)` after fetching the response does the execution just time out?

Comment: The data is exported from BigQuery in this format:
`{“param1”: “value1”, “param2”: “value2”}\n`
`{“param3”: “value3”, “param4”: “value4”}`
The response is recognized as an object, but I’m unable to access any of the parameters as it’s essentially one large object. You’re correct that it doesn’t register as valid `JSON`. Running `let json = JSON.parse(response)` gives me the error `Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1766`. This is presumably because the elements are not comma separated. I’m trying to split the object and parse each individually for this reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### As doubleunary said, you are likely missing `.getContentText()`

Summary: That the `response` from:

```
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
```

Is an `HTTPResponseObject`, so trying to parse it as a string or JSON won't work. To fix it you need to add in a call to `getContentText()`.

Except doubleunary's answer won't work because the result is BigQuery newline delimited JSON, so you will still need to split it by newlines as you have suggested.

So just adding that step:

```js
function myFunction() {

let url = 'url_address';
let storedData = [];
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
let contentText = response.getContentText();
let storedResponse = contentText.split("\n");

storedResponse.forEach((data) => {
   storedData.push(JSON.parse(data));
});
}
```

Should solve your issue, give it a try (seeing as I can't test it).

#### Reference

- [HTTPResponseObject](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)

#### Edit:

Its possible that you may get a few JSON lines being invalid due to the presence of a newline character that is *within* the JSON.

A way to minimize this would be to split by a closing curly brace and a newline
`"}\n"`. Though in theory, a JSON line could also contain this.

```js
function myFunction() {

let url = 'url_address';
let storedData = [];
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
let contentText = response.getContentText();
let storedResponse = contentText.split("}\n");

storedResponse.forEach((data) => {
   storedData.push(JSON.parse(data + "}")); // you would need to add the ending brace again to parse it
});
}
```

Another approach you could take, if the JSON structure is always the same, is to use a regex like this one:

```
^{.+"issues":\[.+\]}$/gm
```

Which looks for chunks of text that start with a newline, and `{` with a variable amount of content inbetween, and then having `"issues":[` with another variable about of data and finally `]}\n`. This should catch most instances of possible newlines within a JSON that are causing the malformed JSONs coming out the `split`. The `gm` is the global flag allowing multiple results and the `m` is the multiline flag that allows you to identify line starts and ends with the `^` and `$` characters.

You could implement it with `string.match`:

```js
function myFunction() {

let url = 'url_address';
let storedData = [];
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
let contentText = response.getContentText();
let storedResponse = contentText.match(/^{.+"issues":\[\]}$/gm);

storedResponse.forEach((data) => {
   storedData.push(JSON.parse(data));
});
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue, thanks for your help. For anyone else with this problem I found I had to wrap the logic in the forEach in a try/catch as one object was improperly formatted and was returning an error

Comment: The improper formatting could also be due to one of the values _within_ the json having a newline. I will edit my answer to provide a possible workaround for this

Answer (score 1):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` will get you an [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) object rather than a JSON string. You will need to get the *contents* of the response like this:

```
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  const str = response.getContentText();
  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
```